# How to fire 2 events together for bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have below 2 events for bootstrap modal

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {

});

$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {

});
```

I have same code in both events.

Can I call both together at one time only for code optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal hidden.bs.modal', function() {

});
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can store your function in a variable.

```
var fnCallback = function() {
  //my function
  console.log('my function was triggered');
};

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', fnCallback);
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', fnCallback);
```

Comment: Is it possible `$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal, hidden.bs.modal', fnCallback);` ?

Comment: To bind multiple events, just separate with spaces (not comma): `$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal hidden.bs.modal', fnCallback);`